# How do I inherit from union'd pydantic models

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Currently I have quite a few models defined and I want a single endpoint that can receive and return them.

My models are all different, e.g.

```
class A(BaseModel):
  foo: str

class B(BaseModel):
  bar: str

All = Union[A, B]
```

Considering the case where my endpoint accepts a body of the form `All`, and returns a new resource of that same form. I want to be able to specify that the return type `All` is `All` plus an extra `id` field.

i.e.

```
RequestAll = Union[A,B]

class ResponseAll(RequestAll):
  id = str
```

However, when I do this, I get an error:

```
__init__() takes 2 positional [but more were given]
```

Another approach I could take is to have a `RequestA` and `ResponseA` equivalent for every type, then union Requests and Responses respectively. However, I would prefer to avoid this given the amount of types I actually have.

Is there a neat way to address this problem?

Comment: I suspect inheritance is the wrong way to go about this. Have you considered composition instead? That is, give your `Response` type a member that is typehinted as a `ResponseAll`?

Comment: A Union is not a class that you can inherit from as it gives no inheritance semantics, it's just a way to say "it can be either a or b". The straight forward solution would be to have `ResponseAll(BaseModel): id: str, response: RequestAll`